# Cannot get logged in customer id from Block class?

Tags: magento2

I am avoiding using the object manager directly, but I cannot get this injected session to return a customer id?

```
...
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
...

class Summary extends Template
{

    protected $_session;

    public function __construct(
        Session $session,
        Quote $quote, 
        Template\Context $context, 
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->_quote = $quote;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    var_dump($this->_session->getCustomerId());

    // Returns null.
```

Comment: have you check customer is logged in or not?

Comment: The customer is definitely logged in... it's me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get current customer id using,

```
    protected $currentCustomer;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->currentCustomer = $currentCustomer;           
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

    public function getCustomerId(){
          return $this->currentCustomer->getCustomerId();
    }
```

Comment: Is this working? plz remove var and check.

Comment: No, that won't work. I had to inject my model with customer/session rather than using session in a block class.

Really good idea though, thanks.